# How to Extract All the keys from an Object in TypeScript

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I am creating a dynamic table headings in Typescript, where the headings are retrieved from the response after subscribing. In order to do it, I need to extract keys from the response(which is in Json). 
I would request you to help me on this.

My [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5fxcqr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) Link is:

Comment: When searching for your answer, feel free to leave off "in TypeScript". TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript, so answers to how to do something in JavaScript are going to be the same.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `Object.keys(obj)`:

```js
const myObj = { someKey: "someValue" };
const keys = Object.keys(myObj); // ["someKey"]
```

Or use a `for` `in` loop:

```js
for(const key in myObj) console.log(key);
```

Comment: But that is not possible on Type Script file.

Comment: I was able to [run it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=6&ssc=43&pln=6&pc=22#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgTwPICMBWMC8MDeAoGQmCEOAUwGkyEAuGAIhPIDUBDAGwFcz6AaAokzJIoACzIAnKrQZCR4iWy49+AXwDcePADMQEmAApQkWAGtqMAJZh4ydAEoYxkuzIA6diADmB8wnvqQA) fine in TypeScript playground. Screenshot [here](https://i.imgur.com/TKTvqqr.png).